# Windows Server 2012 applocker does not work on Windows 10

Tags: windows, group-policy, applocker

Configured applocker to prevent opening cmd , go to system services application identity=automatic,preferences services=application identity set to automatic, 
link the gpo(applocker) to the whole domain somehow, it only works on the domain computer itself ,and windows 8 clients, doesnt work on Windows 10

Am i missing something,please let me know ?

Comment: What has this got to do with VMware?

Comment: im  simulating  active directory and gpo  on vmware i have domain controller (Server 1 Windows 2012) and clients Windows 10,8 im not sure if  vmware is the cause of the problem

Comment: How could the VMware part of this be the issue, especially given you've not provided us with any details about that part of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

AppLocker Policies are strictly enforced for Enterprise OS (Education* for Windows 10 too).

Make sure the correct OS is used and no WMI filter are used that would block the GPO from appling the settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !